# How to create a connection to a remote Spark server and read in data from ipython running on local machine?

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, hdfs, jupyter-notebook

I am running `ipython notebook` on my local machine and want to create a connection to a remote `Spark` server i.p. and then read in data from `hdfs` folder present on the `remote server`. How can I create such a remote connection to a Spark server from local `ipython notebook`?

Answer (score 7):

Are there any particular reasons the notebook has to run from your local machine? If not, it will be as easy as

1. Install jupyter/ipython on the remote machine running spark
   `remote$ pip install "jupyter[all]"`
2. Modify spark-env.sh and add the two lines
   `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7 #your location may vary`
   `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/ipython`
3. Launch pyspark
   `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --no-browser --port=7777" pyspark`
4. On your local machine, set up an ssh tunnel
   `ssh -i private_key  -N -f -L localhost:7776:localhost:7777  ubuntu@remote.com`
5. On your local browser, visit http://localhost:7776

You may want to run #3 behind screen/tmux to maintain it for longer duration.

Some helpful pages:
[1]. http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html
[2]. http://blog.insightdatalabs.com/jupyter-on-apache-spark-step-by-step

Comment: I can't install anything in the server because I'm not the admin.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [SparkMagic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic).

SparkMagic is a client of [Livy](https://github.com/cloudera/livy) that can run within Jupyter notebooks. When we write Spark code on the local Jupyter client,  SparkMagic runs the Spark job 
 remotely through livy.

Using SparkMagic + Jupyter notebook, we can use Spark from our local Jupyter notebook, which is running on our localhost, and then use it to connect to a remote Spark cluster